# Can't change font size when appending svg text/textPath on path

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to append text to path dynamically. And this is working ok, I can see the text.

```
<svg id="karta" 
     :class="name"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xml:space="preserve" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
     shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" 
     text-rendering="geometricPrecision" 
     image-rendering="optimizeQuality" 
     viewBox="900000 400000 8200000 7500000"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 ......

<path id="au" d="M7876412 6521261l126815 -3413 82429 -1949 90236 484 83906 -484 83398 
2929c31216,1630 61169,3189 93649,4878l148276 13783c42673,4158 84862,8540 127299,16099 
29670,4642 58748,10334 88288,15744l82429 16807 91205 21201 81460 18673 83398 18886 
129744 30508"/>

var svg = d3.select("#karta")
var gline = svg.select("#g_line")
gline.append("text")
   .style("font-size", "20000px")
   .append("textPath")
   .style("text-anchor", "start")
   .attr("xlink:href", "#au")
   .text("My text")
```

[image: )]

Text is visible for font size between approx. 1000 and 20000px. But for my project this is too small, I need text to be significantly larger. And I am stack. After a lot of reading I believe that this is related with viewBox but I don't really have a clue how to solve this and not rally understanding why this is happening.
My viewBox have this strange huge numbers because my data come from CorelDraw and if I want good data I need to use drawing precision 1:10000 units. Consequently viewBox have this high numbers.

Comment: browsers don't really support very small or very large numbers very well.

Comment: Either you divide every coordinate you have by factor 1000 or you scale your text with transform. I would go for the first solution.

Comment: @Robert Longson I read about it too, but I didn't have choice as I said. Still hope someone would have some kind of suggestion.

Comment: @Fuzzyma My data are svg, mostly paths...so not sure how coordinates goes with paths? So if I want to scale text can you please give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: You can parse the d attribute of paths and just scale the coordinates. For scaling you just do `transform="scale(100)"`

Comment: @Fuzzyma Unfortunately I can not solve this, font size doesn't change no matter what I do